# FactoryBot :association creates a second parent object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a rails 7.1 app.

A `program` can have many `program_media` and one of them is the `main_program_media`:

```rb
class Program < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :program_medias,
           inverse_of: :program, dependent: :destroy
          class_name: 'ProgramMedia',
          inverse_of: :program,
          dependent: :destroy

  has_one :main_program_media, -> { main },
          class_name: 'ProgramMedia',
          inverse_of: :program,
          dependent: :destroy
end
```

```rb
class ProgramMedia < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :program, inverse_of: :program_medias
  scope :main, -> { where(main: true) }
end
```

I have a trait in my program factory so that a main program media is created:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :program do
    trait :with_main_program_media do
      association :main_program_media, factory: %i[program_media main]
    end
  end 
end
```

However, we are seeing that the following line:

```
FactoryBot.create(:program, :with_main_program_media)
```

creates not 1 but 2 programs. The `program_media`'s program is a different one (not the one that invoked the factory).

I can fix it by changing the factory trait to:

```rb
trait :with_main_program_media do
  after(:build) do |program|
    program.main_program_media = build(:program_media, :main) # notice no need to manually assign the program which means associations are correctly set up
  end
end
```

but I think there's an underlying issue with how factory bot is working, because I would have expected the first to work in the same way as the second. What am I missing?
The issue is the same with a `has_one`, and the fact that I'm using a scope in the association doesn't seem to change anything.